# tf.parse_example for examples with sequence of sequence data

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, google-cloud-ml-engine

My Tensorflow model takes in a sequence of sequence data for each example, namely, sequences of character tokens in a sequence of words (e.g., [[3], [4,3],[6,1,20]]). I was able to do this before by padding a 3D numpy array [batch_size, max_words_len, max_chars_len] and feeding that into a placeholder.

```
in_question_chars = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, 
                                   [None, None, None], 
                                   name="in_question_chars")
# example of other data
in_question_words = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, 
                                   [None, None], 
                                   name="in_question_words")
```

But now I would like to use Google Cloud Machine Learning Engine for online prediction/deployment. Based on the example from Tensorflow Serving: https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_saved_model.py

I came up with something like this but don't really know what to use for the feature to parse the sequence of sequence char tokens:

```
serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(tf.string, name='tf_example')
feature_configs = {'in_question_chars':tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature(shape=[None], 
                                       allow_missing=True, 
                                       dtype=tf.int32, 
                                       default_value=0), 
                   'in_question_words':tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature(shape=[], 
                                       allow_missing=True, 
                                       dtype=tf.int32, 
                                       default_value=0)
                   }

tf_example = tf.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, feature_configs)

in_question_chars = tf.identity(tf_example['in_question_chars'], 
                                name='in_question_chars')
# example of other data
in_question_words = tf.identity(tf_example['in_question_words'], 
                                name='in_question_words')
```

Should I use VarLenFeature, which turns it into a SparseTensor (eventhough it's not really sparse), and then use tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense to convert it back to dense?

For the next step, I get the embedding for each char token.

```
in_question_char_repres = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(char_embedding, 
                                                 in_question_chars)
```

So another option is to keep it a SparseTensor and then use tf.nn.embedding_lookup_sparse

I wasn't able to find an example of how this should be done. Please let me know what is best practice. Thanks!

---

Edit 8/25/17

It doesn't seem to allow me to set None for the 2nd dimension.

Here's an abridged version of my code

```
def read_dataset(filename, mode=tf.contrib.learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN):  
    def _input_fn():
        num_epochs = MAX_EPOCHS if mode == tf.contrib.learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN else 1

        input_file_names = tf.train.match_filenames_once(str(filename))

        filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
            input_file_names, num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=True)
        reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
        _, serialized = reader.read_up_to(filename_queue, num_records=batch_size)

        features_spec = {
            CORRECT_CHILD_NODE_IDX: tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[],
                                               dtype=tf.int64, 
                                               default_value=0),
            QUESTION_LENGTHS: tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[], dtype=tf.int64),
            IN_QUESTION_WORDS: tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature(shape=[], 
                                                      allow_missing=True, 
                                                      dtype=tf.int64
                                                      ),
            QUESTION_CHAR_LENGTHS: tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature(shape=[], 
                                                          allow_missing=True, 
                                                          dtype=tf.int64
                                                          ),
            IN_QUESTION_CHARS: tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature(shape=[None], 
                                                      allow_missing=True, 
                                                      dtype=tf.int64
                                                      )
            }
        examples = tf.parse_example(serialized, features=features_spec)

        label = examples[CORRECT_CHILD_NODE_IDX]
        return examples, label   # dict of features, label
    return _input_fn
```

When I have 'None' for the shape, it gives me this error:

```
    INFO:tensorflow:Using default config.
INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'_task_type': None, '_task_id': 0, '_cluster_spec': <tensorflow.python.training.server_lib.ClusterSpec object at 0x7f57fc309c18>, '_master': '', '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_num_worker_replicas': 0, '_environment': 'local', '_is_chief': True, '_evaluation_master': '', '_tf_config': gpu_options {
  per_process_gpu_memory_fraction: 1.0
}
, '_tf_random_seed': None, '_save_summary_steps': 100, '_save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_log_step_count_steps': 100, '_session_config': None, '_save_checkpoints_steps': None, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_model_dir': 'outputdir'}
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/jupyter-admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/monitors.py:269: BaseMonitor.__init__ (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.monitors) is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-12-05.
Instructions for updating:
Monitors are deprecated. Please use tf.train.SessionRunHook.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/jupyter-admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl(op, input_tensors_needed, input_tensors_as_shapes_needed, require_shape_fn)
    653           graph_def_version, node_def_str, input_shapes, input_tensors,
--> 654           input_tensors_as_shapes, status)
    655   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as err:

/home/jupyter-admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     88             try:
---> 89                 next(self.gen)
     90             except StopIteration:

/home/jupyter-admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status()
    465           compat.as_text(pywrap_tensorflow.TF_Message(status)),
--> 466           pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
    467   finally:

InvalidArgumentError: dense_shapes[2] has unknown rank or unknown inner dimensions: [?,?] for 'ParseExample/ParseExample' (op: 'ParseExample') with input shapes: [?], [0], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [0], [1], [], [], [0], [], [0], [0], [0].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-392858a0e7b4> in <module>()
     48 
     49 shutil.rmtree('outputdir', ignore_errors=True) # start fresh each time
---> 50 learn_runner.run(experiment_fn, 'outputdir')

/home/jupyter-admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_runner.py in run(experiment_fn, output_dir, schedule, run_config, hparams)
    207   schedule = schedule or _get_default_schedule(run_config)
    208 
--> 209   return _execute_schedule(experiment, schedule)
    210 
    211 

/home/jupyter-admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_runner.py in _execute_schedule(experiment, schedule)
     44     logging.error('Allowed values for this experiment are: %s', valid_tasks)
     45     raise TypeError('Schedule references non-callable member %s' % schedule)
---> 46   return task()
     47 
     48 

/home/jupyter-admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/experiment.py in train_and_evaluate(self)
    500             name=eval_dir_suffix, hooks=self._eval_hooks
    501         )]
--> 502       self.train(delay_secs=0)
    503 
    504     eval_result = self._call_evaluate(input_fn=self._eval_input_fn,

/home/jupyter-admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/experiment.py in train(self, delay_secs)
    278     return self._call_train(input_fn=self._train_input_fn,
    279                             max_steps=self._train_steps,
--> 280                             hooks=self._train_monitors + extra_hooks)
    281 
    282   def evaluate(self, delay_secs=None, name=None):

/home/jupyter-admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/experiment.py in _call_train(self, _sentinel, input_fn, steps, hooks, max_steps)
    675                                  steps=steps,
    676                                  max_steps=max_steps,
--> 677                                  monitors=hooks)
    678 
    679   def _call_evaluate(self, _sentinel=None,  # pylint: disable=invalid-name,

/home/jupyter-admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
    294               'in a future version' if date is None else ('after %s' % date),
    295               instructions)
--> 296       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    297     return tf_decorator.make_decorator(func, new_func, 'deprecated',
    298                                        _add_deprecated_arg_notice_to_docstring(

/home/jupyter-admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py in fit(self, x, y, input_fn, steps, batch_size, monitors, max_steps)
    456       hooks.append(basic_session_run_hooks.StopAtStepHook(steps, max_steps))
    457 
--> 458     loss = self._train_model(input_fn=input_fn, hooks=hooks)
    459     logging.info('Loss for final step: %s.', loss)
    460     return self

/home/jupyter-admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py in _train_model(self, input_fn, hooks)
    954       random_seed.set_random_seed(self._config.tf_random_seed)
    955       global_step = contrib_framework.create_global_step(g)
--> 956       features, labels = input_fn()
    957       self._check_inputs(features, labels)
    958       model_fn_ops = self._get_train_ops(features, labels)

<ipython-input-44-fdb63ed72b90> in _input_fn()
     35                                                           )
     36             }
---> 37         examples = tf.parse_example(serialized, features=features_spec)
     38 
     39         label = examples[CORRECT_CHILD_NODE_IDX]

/home/jupyter-admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/parsing_ops.py in parse_example(serialized, features, name, example_names)
    573   outputs = _parse_example_raw(
    574       serialized, example_names, sparse_keys, sparse_types, dense_keys,
--> 575       dense_types, dense_defaults, dense_shapes, name)
    576   return _construct_sparse_tensors_for_sparse_features(features, outputs)
    577 

/home/jupyter-admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/parsing_ops.py in _parse_example_raw(serialized, names, sparse_keys, sparse_types, dense_keys, dense_types, dense_defaults, dense_shapes, name)
    698         dense_keys=dense_keys,
    699         dense_shapes=dense_shapes,
--> 700         name=name)
    701     # pylint: enable=protected-access
    702 

/home/jupyter-admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_parsing_ops.py in _parse_example(serialized, names, sparse_keys, dense_keys, dense_defaults, sparse_types, dense_shapes, name)
    174                                 dense_defaults=dense_defaults,
    175                                 sparse_types=sparse_types,
--> 176                                 dense_shapes=dense_shapes, name=name)
    177   return _ParseExampleOutput._make(result)
    178 

/home/jupyter-admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py in apply_op(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    765         op = g.create_op(op_type_name, inputs, output_types, name=scope,
    766                          input_types=input_types, attrs=attr_protos,
--> 767                          op_def=op_def)
    768         if output_structure:
    769           outputs = op.outputs

/home/jupyter-admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in create_op(self, op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs, op_def, compute_shapes, compute_device)
   2630                     original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
   2631     if compute_shapes:
-> 2632       set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
   2633     self._add_op(ret)
   2634     self._record_op_seen_by_control_dependencies(ret)

/home/jupyter-admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in set_shapes_for_outputs(op)
   1909       shape_func = _call_cpp_shape_fn_and_require_op
   1910 
-> 1911   shapes = shape_func(op)
   1912   if shapes is None:
   1913     raise RuntimeError(

/home/jupyter-admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in call_with_requiring(op)
   1859 
   1860   def call_with_requiring(op):
-> 1861     return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)
   1862 
   1863   _call_cpp_shape_fn_and_require_op = call_with_requiring

/home/jupyter-admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py in call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn)
    593     res = _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl(op, input_tensors_needed,
    594                                   input_tensors_as_shapes_needed,
--> 595                                   require_shape_fn)
    596     if not isinstance(res, dict):
    597       # Handles the case where _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl calls unknown_shape(op).

/home/jupyter-admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl(op, input_tensors_needed, input_tensors_as_shapes_needed, require_shape_fn)
    657       missing_shape_fn = True
    658     else:
--> 659       raise ValueError(err.message)
    660 
    661   if missing_shape_fn:

ValueError: dense_shapes[2] has unknown rank or unknown inner dimensions: [?,?] for 'ParseExample/ParseExample' (op: 'ParseExample') with input shapes: [?], [0], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [0], [1], [], [], [0], [], [0], [0], [0].
```

Currently, I'm getting around this by turning the 2D sequence of sequence into 1D sequence by setting the second dimension to a max_char_length and then concatenating it into a 1d array. So I keep only the first max_char_length char if it's longer than max_char_length or pad it with zeros if it's shorter. This seems to work but perhaps there's a way where it can accept variable length sequence for the second dimension and do padding in tf.parse_example or tf.train.batch.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: fixed confusing/wrong answer =)

So what you want is a [`tf.SequenceExample`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/core/example/example.proto#L292) which uses [`tf.parse_single_sequence_example`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/parse_single_sequence_example) rather than `tf.parse_example`. This allows you to have each feature in the `feature_list` within an example be part of a sequence, in this case each `Feature` can be a `VarLenFeature` representing the number of characters in the word. Unfortunately, this doesn't work as well when you want to pass *multiple* sentences. So we have to do some hacking around with higher order functions and `tf.sparse_concat`:

I produced a test program that does this here: https://gist.github.com/elibixby/1c7a2497f96a457130241c59c676ebd4

The input (before serialization to a batch of `SequenceExamples`) looks like:

```
[[[5, 10], [5, 10, 20]],
 [[0, 1, 2], [2, 1, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3]]]
```

The resulting `SparseTensor` looks like:

```
SparseTensorValue(indices=array([[[0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 2],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 2],
    [1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 2],
    [1, 2, 0],
    [1, 2, 1],
    [1, 2, 2],
    [1, 2, 3]]]), values=array([[ 5, 10,  5, 10, 20,  0,  1,  2,  2,  1,  0,  0,  1,  2,  3]]), dense_shape=array([[2, 3, 4]]))
```

Which appears to be a SparseTensor where `index=[sentence, word, letter]`

Comment: Hey Cliff, I fixed this answer, now that I have a better understanding of what you want to do. Turned out to be pretty hard so let me know if that works for you =)